# default values for different mysql server version

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php project where I use a self-made wrapper for mysqli extension. It works for *select*, *update* and *delete* statements, but not for *insert*.

For example I have a table with three fields - id, name, surname.
The insert query looks like this:

```
$add = new SqlQuery();
$add->addField('id', 1);
$add->addField('name', 'Alex');
$add->execute();
```

and it fails always, because the sql server has no default value for the `surname` field.
But for some mystery reasons this code works on production server.

Are there any differences for default values setting for different mysql server versions?
Or, is there any option or parameter, how I can manage such behavior for mysql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is database configuration. Property called sql_mode, and more exactly - strict_trans_tables, or strict_all_tables. If any of this options is enabled, database will throw error in this case (look question) and warning if options disabled.

There is reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify a default value for the surname field or insert a placeholder value yourself.

An insert statement will always fail on the MySQL side otherwise. I'm not sure why is it working on your production servers if there's really no default value specified either but on my opinion it's bad practice to leave such holes in your data anyways.

So even if the user didn't gave or haven't specified a certain data that you should store I advise for choosing a default placeholder yourself - be it just plain NULL value or empty strings or whatever but it will be easier to work with your data later if you have that set up properly.

Comment: This is third-party service, and I can't manage it directly (code and sql). I have it source codes, and I found there shell, and this shell is not closed in production server, lol. So, I look in production server codes, and it look like my. But it work on prod, but not work for me.